# How can I make longtable in subtable?

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, subcaption

How can I embed `longtable` in `subtable`?
If I use like this, `longtable` does not work.

```
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\caption{aa}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ccccccc@{}}
...
\end{longtable}
\end{subtable}
```

Comment: You can't (on showed way). Long tables should not be enclosed in float environment or boxes etc. Well, if table can be fit on one page, than instead  `longtable` you can use ordinary tables which can be part od `subtable` environments

Answer (score 1):

The `subtable` environment that's provided by the `subcaption` package is, for all intents and purposes, nothing but a LaTeX `minipage` environment that's been told what it has to do if it encounters a `\caption` directive in its scope. Importantly, LaTeX `minipage` environments are not allowed to contain page breaks. That is why you cannot embed a `longtable` environment inside a `subtable` environment.

You may want to (or have to) rethink your approach to organizing the tabular material in your document. Ordinarily, `subtable` environments are intended to be used to typeset fairly small and self-contained `tabular`-like material (and its associated (sub-)caption); moreover, `subtable`s are intended to be used within a larger `table`-like structure. If the tabular material is sufficiently voluminous as to require a `longtable` (and, presumably, one or more page breaks), it is simply *not advisable*, from a typographic point of view, to embed this voluminous material in a `subtable` environment (which, as noted above, will be embedded in a `table` environment).